# Automatically show related sections in a multi window setup

Tags: org-mode

**Context** I have a document with recurring section structures, similiar to this:

```
* Section
****** Goals
****** Strategy
****** Bibliography
****** Notes
```

and usually an emacs frame with four windows inside where three of those windows are showing the Goals, the Strategy and the Bibliography subsections according to the section I am working in.

**Question** How can I register a callback handler that can receive the section I am working on in the fourth window and is able to change the view port of the other three windows such that Goal, Strategy and Bibliography are visible accordingly?

Comment: What you are describing is a lenticular text feature that is implemented in Phillip Lord's package called lentic. It is available on melpa repository. Lentic may require you tweak the configuration for your specific document structure, but it is a general solution to two-way editing, two-way viewing, and live sync of various parts of the same document.